# Only can read 5 gmail messages Gmail API

Tags: c#, gmail-api

I'm making a small Windows Application for my project. I followed the document of Google and some people in this forum to write a method to read all Gmail messages in "INBOX" of my Gmail. I could get Gmail messages in its body part but I just could get 5 emails instead of all of my email messages. I tried to use the property "MaxResult" to set maximum emails that I wanted to get but nothing happened.

This is my method:

```
 private async Task GetMAILs()
    {
        try
        {
            UserCredential credential;
            using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows for read-only access to the authenticated 
                    // user's account, but not other types of account access.
                    new[] { GmailService.Scope.GmailReadonly, GmailService.Scope.MailGoogleCom, GmailService.Scope.GmailModify },
                    "an thanh",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(this.GetType().ToString())
                );
            }

            var gmailService = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
            });


            //var request = new UsersResource.MessagesResource.ListRequest(gmailService, "me");

            var emailListRequest = gmailService.Users.Messages.List("mymail@gmail.com");
            emailListRequest.LabelIds = "INBOX";
            //emailListRequest.IncludeSpamTrash = false;
            emailListRequest.Q = "in:unread in:inbox"; 
            emailListRequest.MaxResults = 100;

            //get our emails
            var emailListResponse = await emailListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

            if (emailListResponse != null && emailListResponse.Messages != null)
            {
                //loop through each email and get what fields you want...
                foreach (var email in emailListResponse.Messages)
                {
                    //FORM.MessageBox.Show(email.Id);
                    //var request = new UsersResource.MessagesResource.ListRequest(gmailService, "me");
                    //IList<Message> messages = request.Execute().Messages;
                    string from = "";
                    string date = "";
                    string subject = "";
                    string decoded = "";


                    var emailInfoRequest = gmailService.Users.Messages.Get("mymail@gmail.com",email.Id);
                    //make another request for that email id...
                    var emailInfoResponse = await emailInfoRequest.ExecuteAsync();

                    if (emailInfoResponse != null)
                    {

                        //loop through the headers and get the fields we need...
                        foreach (var mParts in emailInfoResponse.Payload.Headers)
                        {
                            if (mParts.Name == "Date")
                            {
                                date = mParts.Value;
                            }
                            else if (mParts.Name == "From")
                            {
                                from = mParts.Value;
                            }
                            else if (mParts.Name == "Subject")
                            {
                                subject = mParts.Value;
                            }
                        }

                        foreach (var ms_part in emailInfoResponse.Payload.Parts)
                        {
                                if (ms_part.MimeType == "text/plain")
                                {
                                    byte[] data = FromBase64ForUrlString(ms_part.Body.Data);
                                    decoded = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
                                }
                        }
                    }
                    bd.AppendLine(string.Format("Từ: {0}", from));
                    bd.AppendLine(subject);
                    bd.AppendLine(date);
                    bd.AppendLine("Content: ");
                    bd.AppendLine(decoded);
                    bd.AppendLine("-------End-------");
                    bd.AppendLine("----------------------------------------------------");
                    //now you have the data you want....
                    richTextBox1.Text = bd.ToString();
                }

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            FORM.MessageBox.Show("Failed to get messages!: " + ex.Message, "Failed Messages!", FORM.MessageBoxButtons.OK);

        }
    }
```

Method to convert Binary data to String:

```
 public byte[] FromBase64ForUrlString(string base64ForUrlInput)
    {
        int padChars = (base64ForUrlInput.Length % 4) == 0 ? 0 : (4 - (base64ForUrlInput.Length % 4));
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(base64ForUrlInput, base64ForUrlInput.Length + padChars);
        result.Append(String.Empty.PadRight(padChars, '='));
        result.Replace('-', '+');
        result.Replace('_', '/');
        return Convert.FromBase64String(result.ToString());
    }
```

Method to call Task "GetMAILs()":

```
 private void btGet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Test2();
    }
    private async void Test2()
    {
        await GetMAILs();
    }
```

Sorry I'm just a freshman with Gmail API. I'll be grateful for anyhelp from everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Must be an issue with your filters. You can start by removing this line:

```
  emailListRequest.Q = "in:unread in:inbox";
```

or change it to:

```
emailListRequest.Q = "in:inbox";
```

Seems to work when I used it in Users.messages: list [Try-it](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list#try-it).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried with emailListRequest.Q = "in:inbox". But I still have 5 emails.

Comment: I just want to get all emails in each page in my "INBOX"

Answer (score 0):

Try to change to this:

```
emailListRequest.Q = "is:unread label:INBOX"
```

I also try something and this work. You also may use this [link](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en) to see params alow by gmail API

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: add context around the link so your users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable.